# Does Fun Tak work as a temporary solder alternative?

Tags: connectors

I'm interested in making connections to gpio and breadboards strong enough to jostle around a bit, but make them temporary enough to change on a whim. A recent MagPi article mentions Blu-tack and Plasticine. I have [Fun Tak](http://www.loctiteproducts.com/p/cntct_putty/overview/Loctite-Fun-Tak-Mounting-Putty.htm) on hand, but don't want to use it if it will "muck up" my Pi. Does anyone have any experience using this product on their electronic projects?

Comment: I too would be interested in any solder alternative.  I don't mind soldering permanent connections but for temporary stuff being able to stick a resistor to an LED or something like that should make breadboarding easier.

Comment: I have used wire wrap for such connections before nicely

Comment: Isn't this the point of the breadboard itself?

Comment: Just try not to hit any actual electronics on the board. Try to avoid capacitors, ICs, SD connector, and sharp solder joints (opposite side of the GPIO connector, etc.). I suggest using small blobs on empty areas instead of a giant blob just stuck to the pi.

Answer (score 1):

Soldered joints ensure both good mechanical and electrical connections - fun Tak is unlikely to provide a suitable mechanical bond in such small spaces, nor is it likely to have proper electrical conductivity.

However, something like the [Pi Cobbler and ribbon cable](https://www.adafruit.com/products/914) from Adafruit will allow you to separate the Pi and the breadboard when desired and not require any soldering (assuming you buy a preassembled version).

You don't mention what model Pi you are using but some soldering may be required if using the the new Pi Zero - which does not have the GPIO pins populated) If using the Pi Zero this affords some additional options. In addition to the standard male pins you could use a female header, this would allow using standard male to male jumper wires to connect to your breadboard, Additionally you could use a set of right angle headers to create a vertical mounting for the Pi above the breadboard (akin to a video card mount in a PC).